# how to get the next hour's date string in bash

Tags: bash, date

I 'm using bash
I have a date string now, for example:

```
2015111301
```

(yyyymmddHH)

how to get the date string of next hour?
that is:

```
2015111302
```

Comment: How are you getting the initial string?

Comment: @asimovwasright `date +%Y%m%d%H` can get you such output

Comment: @Ashish, yes, I know how to get the format, the question was meant for the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
in="2015111301"
out="$(date -d "${in:0:8} ${in:8:2}:00:00 +1hour" '+%Y%m%d%H')"
echo "$out"
```

Output:

```
2015111302
```

See: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32)

Comment: why I am getting `2015111306` output in cygwin

Comment: I don't know. Tested with bash 4.2.8 and date from GNU coreutils 8.5.

Comment: I am getting same output in Ubuntu 15 LTS now

Answer (score 0):

This below script worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash
tempval=$(echo 2015111301 | sed 's/\(.\{8\}\)/\1 /g')
tempval=$(echo "$tempval 1 hour")
date -d "$tempval" +%Y%m%d%H
```